# The problem is during the input of structure variables,after some inputs it doesnt print input statements and assigns input to variable randomly

Tags: c, arrays, input, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct complex {
  int real;
  int img;
} s1[2], s2;

int main() {
  int n;
  printf("\t******MAIN MENU*******\n");
  printf(
      "1-Read Complex number\n2-Display Complex number\n3-Add\n4-Subtract\n5-EXIT\n");

  while (1) {
    printf("Enter your choice \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    switch (n) {
      case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          printf("Enter real and imaginary parts of complex number %d \n",
              i + 1);
          scanf("%d ", &s1[i].real);
          scanf("%d ", &s1[i].img);
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
          printf("Complex number %d = ", j + 1);
          printf("%d + %di\n", s1[j].real, s1[j].img);
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        printf("The sum of two Complex Numbers Are = ");
        s2.real = s1[0].real + s1[1].real;
        s2.img = s1[0].img + s1[1].img;
        printf("%d + %di\n", s2.real, s2.img);
        break;
      case 4:
        printf("The difference of two Complex Numbers Are = ");
        s2.real = s1[0].real - s1[1].real;
        s2.img = s1[0].img - s1[1].img;
        printf("%d + %di", s2.real, s2.img);
        break;
      case 5:
        exit(0);
      default:
        printf("\n Wrong choice \n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "after some inputs" --> What are those inputs?  Note code is using integers and not floating point.

Comment: Usual the first thing to do is to check the return value from `scanf()`.  E.g. `if (scanf("%d", &s1[i].img) != 1) { puts("bad input"); exit(1);`

Comment: While entering 1st Complex number , it takes both real and imaginary part ,But when it comes to taking 2nd complex number it doesnt print the statement "Enter complex number 2" rather it takes another input without printing anything and assigns it to real part of complex number 2 .and then it printd the statement ,"Enter complex number 2 " .And when i enter the value it assign that value to "img" variable rather than real variable.

Comment: So basically its running one step backwards

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks it worked. But can you tell the reason behind it?

Comment: @chux thanx mate . It worked

Answer (score 1):

When you read the parts of the complex number:

```
      scanf("%d ", &s1[i].real);
      scanf("%d ", &s1[i].img);
```

The `%d` format specifier expects a sequence of digits.  The problem is the space after it consumes any number of whitespace characters.  After a number is typed and you press ENTER, the `scanf` doesn't return until some non-whitespace character is entered, i.e. the next number you intend on typing.

Get rid of the trailing space in the format string:

```
      scanf("%d", &s1[i].real);
      scanf("%d", &s1[i].img);
```